# Xamarin HttpClient how to fetch json and use it

Tags: c#, json, xamarin

First I'd like to say that I've been reading over and over hthe https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/cloud-services/consuming/rest/ guide, but it doesn't help.

I have a phpwebservice that returns json when asked:

```
    <?php

include("../include/class.pdogsb.inc.php");


$pdo = PdoGsb::getPdoGsb();


$tabCabinets = $pdo->getLesCabinets();



    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode(array('cabinets'=>$tabCabinets));

?>
```

it gives a response of this type

```
cabinets": [

    {
        "0": "1",
        "1": "2,2891506",
        "2": "48,8618687",
        "3": "75016",
        "4": "Paris",
        "5": "1 Avenue Gustave V de Suède",
        "id": "1",
        "longitudeGPS": "2,2891506",
        "latitudeGPS": "48,8618687",
        "cp": "75016",
        "ville": "Paris",
        "rue": "1 Avenue Gustave V de Suède"
    },
```

In my xamarin PCL project I have created a method that I use when I load my view to fetch that json data.

```
    using Newtonsoft.Json;
    using suivAAndroid.Models;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Net.Http;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace suivAAndroid.ViewModel
    {
        public partial class CreerVisiteViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
        {
            #region propriétés
            private Cabinet unCabinet;
            private Medecin unMedecin;

            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

            #endregion

            #region methods
            public CreerVisiteViewModel()
            {
                loadcabinets();
            }
            private async Task loadcabinets()
            {
                List<Cabinet> listeCabinets = null;
                HttpClient clientCabinets = new HttpClient();
                string url = "http://10.0.0.5/ppe3JoJuAd/gsbAppliFraisV2/webservices/w_cabinet.php";
//does not read the code after this line
                var response = await clientCabinets.GetAsync(new Uri(url));
                string jsonString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                listeCabinets = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Cabinet>>(jsonString);
            }

            #endregion
        }
    }
```

My problem is, while executing and debugging the app, the compiler does not go after the `string url = "10.0.0.5/ppe3JoJuAd/gsbAppliFraisV2/webservices/w_cabinet.php";` line. Instead it returns to `loadcabinets();` which means that the client never fetch the json data.

what can I do ?

Edit: Updated code with recent answers

i created a BaseViewModel where I Implemented the Icommand interface

```
public class RelayCommandAsync : ICommand
    {
        private Func<object, Task> _action;
        private Task _task;

        public RelayCommandAsync(Func<object, Task> action)
        {
            _action = action;
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return _task == null || _task.IsCompleted;
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

        public async void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            _task = _action(parameter);
            OnCanExecuteChanged();
            //await _task;
            //OnCanExecuteChanged();
        }

        private void OnCanExecuteChanged()
        {
            var handler = this.CanExecuteChanged;
            if (handler != null)
                handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
```

Here is the result in my previous ViewModel

```
#region methods
        public CreerVisiteViewModel()
        {


        }
        #endregion
        #region Methods
        public async Task<List<Cabinet>> loadcabinetsAsync()
        {
            List<Cabinet> listeCabinets = null;
            HttpClient clientCabinets = new HttpClient();
            try
            {
                string url = "http://10.0.0.5/ppe3JoJuAd/gsbAppliFraisV2/webservices/w_cabinet.php";
                var uri = new Uri(string.Format(url, string.Empty));
                var response = await clientCabinets.GetAsync(uri);
                string jsonString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                listeCabinets = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Cabinet>>(jsonString);

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

            }
            return listeCabinets;
        }
        #endregion


        #region ICommand
        public ICommand ExecuteLoadCabinetAsync { get { return new RelayCommandAsync(x => loadcabinetsAsync()); } }
        #endregion
```

It still does not resolve my problem with the compiler not reading all the method's code, what can I do more ?

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues here:

1. You are calling a async method without awaiting it.
2. You are calling a async method in a constructor
3. You are calling several async methods right after another, without using ConfigureAwait(false), meaning you are switching context back and forth
4. Your URL does not have a valid scheme, so you are probably getting an exception there

If you want to use the MVVM pattern, you would wrap your code in `ICommand`, and execute that command, to populate a `ObservableCollection`. The execution of that command would happen in a Lifecycle event of your ViewController/Activity/Page depending on what platform you are on.

Comment: How can I resolve 1 and 2 ? I wasn't aware of 3. Indeed I had an invalid uri exception thrown which I resolved by putting http before the whole string.

Comment: Since constructors can't be async, wrap the `loadcabinets();` call in a Task: `Task.Run(async () => await loadcabinets());`.

Comment: As suggested use `ICommand` and execute that. Frameworks like MvvmCross, ReactiveUI, MvvmLight etc. already have implementations ready for use.